# What does the ".classname.active" means in css?

Tags: css

I am new to the css but never faced the code like this can anyone tell me what this piece of code actually means.

```
.icon.active {
    fill: $active;
}
```

Comment: It selects elements that have `.icon` and `.active` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the element has multiple classes. It targets the `.icon` which has `.active` in its class value. It will inherit the properties made in the `.icon` class as well as `.active` if any.

```css
.icon {
  background: lightgray;
  color: black;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.active {
  background: tomato;
}
.icon.active {
  /* Inherits all the properties from .icon class and .active class */
  font-size: 0.75em;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">I am an icon but not active</div>
<br>
<div class="icon active">I am an icon as well as active. So I am lightweight.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.classname.active` is a [sequence of simple selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#sequence-of-simple-selectors) which contains

- The [universal selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#universal-selector) `*`, which is omitted
- The [simple](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn) [class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#class-html) `.classname`
- The [simple](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn) [class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#class-html) `.active`

Therefore, it selects all elements which have the class `classname` and the class `active`.

From the [CSS2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#class-html),

> For example, the following rule matches any P element whose "class"
>   attribute has been assigned a list of space-separated values that
>   includes "pastoral" and "marine":
>
> ```
> p.marine.pastoral { color: green }
> ```

Comment: You do know OP is not actually using `.classname` but `.icon` right? Since OP seems to know so little about CSS, this might be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

This means an element having both classes.

for example:

```
<i class="icon active"></i>
```

this rule will only apply to an element that have both classes.

```css
.icon.active {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  }
```

```html
<p class="icon active">Hello</p>

<p class="icon">Hello</p>
```